# Scala/Python vs. Java: SparkContext.map vs. .filter in PI example?

Tags: java, python, scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

In the Pi example at http://spark.apache.org/examples.html

In the Estimating Pi example, there is a discrepancy in the Python/Scala vs. Java example I don't understand. Python and Scala are both using map and reduce:

Python

```py
def sample(p):
    x, y = random(), random()
    return 1 if x*x + y*y < 1 else 0

count = spark.parallelize(xrange(0, NUM_SAMPLES)).map(sample) \
             .reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
print "Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES)
```

Scala

```scala
val count = spark.parallelize(1 to NUM_SAMPLES).map{i =>
  val x = Math.random()
  val y = Math.random()
  if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
}.reduce(_ + _)
println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES)
```

But Java is using filter:

```java
int count = spark.parallelize(makeRange(1, NUM_SAMPLES)).filter(new    
  Function<Integer, Boolean>() {
    public Boolean call(Integer i) {
      double x = Math.random();
      double y = Math.random();
      return x*x + y*y < 1;
   }
}).count();
System.out.println("Pi is roughly " + 4 * count / NUM_SAMPLES);
```

Is this just a doc typo/bug? Is filter preferable in Java and map/reduce preferred in Scala and Python for some reason?

Comment: I think that since spark is supporting pre-java8 versions, it docs was written on more canonical pre-lambda java. And if they would write implementation with two anonclasses (for map\reduce) it would seem even more monstrous.

Comment: This experience with Spark is really making me want to write this in Scala :) Thanks

Comment: Although It's unacceptible and rude to start such language shittalks in SO, I would say you need just a little bit exprience with any JVM alternative like scala\clojure\groovy to stop wanting coding n java.

Also I would say that semi-dynamic and playful nature of spark dataframes have even more common with clojure than with anything else. So IMO clojure should be *their* next language to introduce. @zero323 could tell you more surely as he is one of *them* - spark contributors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These approaches are equivalent. Java code simply counts cases where Scala / Python map returns 1. Just to make it a little bit more transparent:

```py
def inside(x, y):
    """Check if point (x, y) is inside a unit circle
    with center in the origin (0, 0)"""
    return x*x + y*y < 1

points = ... 

# Scala / Python code is equivalent to this
sum([1 if inside(x, y) else 0 for (x, y) in points])

# While Java code is equivalent to this
len([(x, y) for (x, y) in points if inside(x, y)])
```

Finally sum you get is proportional to the fraction of the area of the enclosing square covered by the circle and from the formula we know it is equal π.

Comment: Thanks I must be a little confused, I will implement these and try them but I thought they are all supposed to approximate pi? I think I don't understand your answer, sorry

Comment: Oh I get it thanks! Was overlooking the obvious. Good answer

Comment: Thanks , and why `4.0 * count / n` could get the final result pi?

Comment: Oh,I get that ,it's the space of a circle and square

Comment: Exactly, you have nice unit circle with area π * 1^2 =  π and square with area 2^2  = 4 hence  π / 4 = count / n =>  π = count * 4 / n